# How to make a script know about a flask parameter?

Tags: javascript, flask

I am using a Flask server. Some of the templates use JavaScript scripts of their own.
One of these scripts generates a svg on the page. This function needs a picture produced by the server.

Here is a simplified version of what exists for now:

template (myTemplate.html):

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <div id="graph">
        <img src="/picture/{{ datasetName }}"></img>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

javascript (script.js):

```
var graph = d3.select("#graph");
var svg = graph.append("svg") //this generates a <svg> in the <div>, it's d3js syntax.
        .attr("width",window.innerWidth)
        .attr("height",window.innerHeight)
        .append("g");
```

flask server (server.py):

```
from flask import *

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def foo():
    return render_template('myTemplate.html')

@app.route('/picture/<datasetName>', methods=['GET'])
def picture(datasetName):
    img = (...) #some function to get my picture
    return send_file(img.to_bytesio(), mimetype='image/svg', cache_timeout=0)
```

My problem is that I would like to be able to use the picture in my javascript (to set it as a background for the svg which will move when navigating in the svg), but currently I have no clean way to get it. I could move the script to the html page but my project is quite big and I want to avoid that.

What would be a clean way to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the loaded image as the background to the generated image is to use a CSS overlay. That requires almost no change to your HTML structure or drawing routines at all.

The CSS would look like:

#graph {
        position: relative;
    }

```
#graph * {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Now everything in `div#graph` overlays each other.

A second way would be to have that loaded image be a part of the CSS `background-image` for the `<div>` or its `<svg>`. CSS has good background image support, with options for stretching, truncating, and tiling. A tutorial [is here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp).

A final option requires more surgery:

1. Remove the `<img ...>` tag
2. Have your D3 code generate an `image` element. The [docs are here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image).

```
<image xlink:href="/picture/..." x="0" y="0"
  height="150" width="250" />
```

This is feasible, but I don't recommend it. CSS has better sizing, positioning, and tiling controls than SVG, esp. relative to the whole browser page. The image parameters often have to be explicitly specified, including image width and height, so you'll have to know or calculate them. And there is the problem of communicating from your template to your JS what the value of `datasetName` is. So...stick with one of the CSS options. Ideally the first.

Comment: Actually I want my background image to zoom in and out when I zoom in and out the svg, so only you last option would work. Like you said, "there is the problem of communicating from your template to your JS what the value of datasetName is", which is exactly the problem I have to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like the following

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <div id="graph">
        <img src="/picture/{{ datasetName }}"></img>
    </div>
    <script>
        var imagePath = '/picture/{{ datasetName }}';
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Basically server-side you generate a client-side script tag, which when executed client-side, would give you `imagePath` variable usable from client-side scripts.

P.S. Just noticed you wanted to avoid that. Sorry.

What you may also have is a URL mapping on the flask server, e.g. `@app.route('/scripts/picture/<datasetName>.js', methods=['GET'])`, that generates client-side script file with parameters that you need client-side on the page.
This way you would keep the script related code separate from your html.